# Copy/Merge multiple HDFS files using Nifi Processor

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi

We have the below requirements in the Nifi flow

a) Fetch a file from HDFS and transfer it to a Linux Server.
I have achieved this using FetchHDFS and PutSFTP NiFi Processors, and it is working fine as expected for a single file.

Now, we have a requirement that this HDFS directory may contain multiple files, and all of them need to be transferred to the Linux server. I tried passing the HDFS directory path in the "HDFS File Name" Property of the FetchHDFS processor; however, it seems to accept only file names. Could you please suggest an alternative processor to achieve this?

I tried to use ListHDFS -> FetchHDFS -> PutSFTP 
Actually, the HDFS files are output of sqoop jobs. I tried connecting RouterAtribute to ListHDFS, but that connection is not allowed.

b) The second requirement is to combine all the files in a specific HDFS directory. Can we achieve this using the MergeContent processor?

Could you please provide some inputs?